# How To Change TypeScript Import Type's Font Color in Visual Studio

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I'm using AMD, and would like to be able to change the font color for imported types:

[image]

Currently this is the default color, is there anyway to configure this color?  Not seeing any way to configure this in the Font/Colors section.

Comment: I don't think you can do it in the settings. Maybe you could do it with a custom color theme?